# How to move files from one directory to another but only move a file each time

Tags: windows, batch-file

Everyday there are more than 2000 files generated, and i want to move the files one by one from one folder to another. I know how to write a batch file for moving whole folder or by prefix of files name and so on. But no idea how to move files one by one.

```
move *.* \newfolder
move *.docx \newfolder
...
```

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by one by one? perhaps with an example or explanation, _because I have a feeling that what you're using is already copying the files one by one, (just very quickly)_. Are you simply wanting to take longer over the process? and are you needing to copy each file in any specific order?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%A in (*) do move /y "%%~A" "\newfolder\"
```

This will move all files in the current directory one by one.
The trailing backslash is for the destination as being a folder.
The leading backslash copied from your code is `newfolder` from
the root of the drive.

`*.docx` is irrelevant once all files have been moved.

Comment: I guess `move /Y "*.*" "\newfolder\"` also moves the files one by one...

Comment: @aschipfl I consider that as many moves done in the 1 process of `move`. You have no ability of control over each file moved with that single command. A `for` loop can be expanded and improved, a single `move` command is limited. What the OP perhaps wants to improve is beyond my knowledge, but your code appears to be ironically similar to the already posted code in the question.

Comment: @michael_heath, I made my comment for further information to attempt to gain that knowledge before considering providing an answer. We have no idea what is meant by one at a time, but must at the same time be aware that with `2000`+ files, any one by one process must not take much more than around `40` seconds in order to complete all within a day.